# PHP web scraping HTMLDOM pagination

Tags: php, web-scraping, pagination, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am scraping this url as it is my final year project but this code only scrape 1 page of searched query I want pagination (like 1,2,3,4,5) at the end please help

I have implemented one data scraping script which fetch data using CURL.

But that fetch record only one page but i want all data because on that page pagination is there.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="home-search">
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
<input type="submit">         
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
$keyword = urlencode($_POST['keyword']);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.bestjobs.co.za/jobs/?q='.$keyword);
//echo $html;
$indeedDotPk = array();
//$html = file_get_contents($result);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="paginas"]/ul/li/a/@href');
$total_pages = 0;
$start = 0;
$job_title_index = 0;
$job_link_index = 0;
$job_description_index = 0;
$job_experience_index = 0;

foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
    $total_pages++;
    // echo $value->textContent;
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo "<br>";
}

for ($i=0; $i < $total_pages; $i++) { 
     ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $html = file_get_contents('https://www.bestjobs.co.za/jobs/?q='.$keyword.'&start='.$start);
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

     // Job Description
    $node = $xpath->query('//a[@class="js-o-link"]');
    foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
        if(is_string($value->textContent)){
            $indeedDotPk[$job_description_index++]['job_description'] = $value->textContent;
        }
    }
    // Job Description

    $start = $start + 10;
}

  foreach ($indeedDotPk as $key => $value) {
   if(!empty($value['job_description'])){

?>

<table border="1">
<tr >
    <td>
       
    </td>

    <td>
   
    </td>

    <td>
      
    </td>

    <td>
        <?php echo $value['job_description']?>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can set pagination in the end like 1,2,3,4,5 ?

If anyone has any suggestion then please help me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Pass the paging parameter in the url like this

```
https://www.bestjobs.co.za/jobs/?q=sales&p=2
```

Wrap everything in a function and using for loop pass the paging parameter to the function like this

```
function webScrape($p){
//scraping code
}

for($i=0;$i>=100;$i++){
webScrape($i);
}
```

Comment: i didnot get it Nitin Sir basically i am student and begineer can you modiefy  my above code to show me how will i do that it would be a great help